# Dividing square into smaller squares by using their shapes rather than their bounding boxes in R

Tags: r, polygon, sf, vector-grid

I want to divide a square into 25 smaller squares. The square layer has a UTM coordinate system, so when plotted, it doesn't have flat bottoms and tops. When I try `st_make_grid()` function to overlay a grid on top of it, it uses bounding box to do that, and I get a grid that doesn't perfectly overlap with the initial square.

See the figure below where the red square is the initial, target square and the grid is the one created by the `st_make_grid()` function. I want to know if there is a way to divide the squares into equal-sized, smaller squares without getting this misalignment problem.

[image]

I'm providing a set of coordinates in "BGS2005_UTM_zone_35N" coordinate system, which you can use to reproduce the original data. Five sets of coordinates are provided for direct use of the `st_polygon()` function.

data.frame(x = c(924081.5, 920804.9, 970816.1, 974096.0, 924081.5), y = c(4260553, 4310549, 4313844, 4263815, 4260553))

Comment: Hack might be to create a 'false' coordinate system, and project your UTM data into that, such that your square becomes orthogonal, and the grid can dice it. But that assumes your original polygon is perfectly square.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have R, but I was able to do this with other software.
I divided all 4 sides and created points in Excel like this:

=-1*(A5-A2)/5+A5

=-2*(A5-A2)/5+A5

=-3*(A5-A2)/5+A5

=-4*(A5-A2)/5+A5

In QGIS I created Lines using Snap-to-Points and then created Polygons by turning on Snap-to-Intersections.
[image]